# "Don't be too forward" OR "Don't be this forward"

Tags: sentence-usage

Suppose you met a guy in a party one month ago. You went out together for two-three times. Even you've exchanged some facts about your lives and know some details of your private lives. Now everyone can call you "friends", though you are “not close friends yet”. Moreover, you have been in his house for one or possibly two times so far. Also you have invited him to your house two or three times. This time when you invite him to your house you begin a discussion about something. The more you discuss about that topic, the more you feel uncomfortable because your girlfriend sits beside you and your friend is talking to you about some issues, which you prefer to be said when you are alone together or you do not want to be said that openly at all. For example he starts speaking about his private affairs with his ex-girlfriend, and subsequently opens some discussions about their private relationship (not merely "very" sexual affairs.) You feel shy beside your girlfriend just because of her being beside you at that moment. Nevertheless you are not going to offend your friend too! First because he is your guest, secondly because you think he is your friend and finally because though his words sound out of place at that specific moment, but if you both had been alone together, you would have listened to his words and perhaps you would participate in that discussion too. Having these all said, now you feel shy and you are going to change the topic or give him a hint that you'd better correct the way you are speaking (because my girlfriend has sat here and of course in an indirect way and with a smile on your lips to avoid him to be upset or feel out of place etc.) Then what would you say? I think for example "**Hey David, don't be too forward**" OR “**don’t be this forward**” (having a smile on your lips) Does it sound a natural statement at this moment?
Any other native’s suggestion would be welcome. :)

Comment: As I understand it, you don't have a problem with what he is saying, just that you don't want him saying those things in front of your friend, right? I don't think that is the same as being forward, which would be toward you. I think its more like "Sam, don't speak out of place" or "Sam, let's talk about such things privately." I suppose there are a number of things you could say. It really depends on your relationships.

Comment: @user3169: That sounds very formal. In fact, "don't speak out of place" sounds pretty condescending and archaic; it's what a person in power says to a slave or underling. (btw lol hi again)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This probably varies alot depending on who is involved. I like to get to the point, and since David isn't being so sensitive... In any case "forward" is not the right word to use here. BTW, I think the slave or underling would more likely get "shut your mouth".

Comment: I don't think e.g. the Queen would say "shut your mouth" to a mouthy servant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, just in terms of grammar, neither one sounds idiomatic to me. If you want to tell him that what he just said was too forward, you would say:

> Don't be **so** forward

If you say:

> Don't be **too** forward

it means you're anticipating him being forward in the future in a specific instance. For example, you might say "go talk to her, but don't be too forward--she doesn't like that."

An easy way to remember the difference: when your friend goes out to a bar, you might tell her, "Don't get too drunk." When she gets home, you would say, "Next time, don't get so drunk." "Too" for the future, "so" for the past.

"This" doesn't work at all in this context.